# Shiny in R: How can I pass a value from a reactive environment in server.R to ui.R?

Tags: r, shiny, global

I have a locally defined vector of values in server.R and would like to use it in ui.R. My idea was the following:

server.R

```
values <- rep(NA, 10)

reactive{(
values[i] <- ... (where i is some index defined as input from ui.R)
})
```

global.R

```
pass <- values
```

So I can use the vector *pass* in the ui-environment. However, this does not work. I guess, global.R and ui.R only know the initial state of the vector *values* and not the updated one. I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: Look into `reactiveValues()`, http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/reactiveValues

Comment: If you want to dynamically change ui elements, look at the `?uiOutput` and `?renderUI` functions.